# Android - Programmatically change EditText selection color

Tags: android

How to programmatically change the color of the background of selected text of EditText?

[image: color of the background of selected text of EditText]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `setHighlightColor` method.

```
editText.setHighlightColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.someColor));
```

If used in Fragment than use this:

```
 editText.setHighlightColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.someColor));
```

And you can set the color at values -> colors.xml

```
<color name="someColor">#3cff00</color>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below command to do this.

```
android:textColorHighlight="#77f442"
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can change the color of the background of selected text of EditText by using `setHighlightColor()` method as:

```
editText.setHighlightColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.someColor));
```